# program runs in eclipse but not in command?(not class undefined or not found)

Tags: java, eclipse, cmd

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AxFw.jpg

[image]
[image]

as shown in the link picture, I am able to compile program properly within eclipse, but not in cmd. I simply do not understand why and in need of help.

to clarify, there are no run config tempered on eclipse.

Comment: Paste and format your code in the question, instead of putting an screenshot! The same applies to the error message!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compile it first.

For example: javac project1

then run it with: java project1

Comment: it seems to run the file, but there is nothing being printed out other than []. [picture](http://imgur.com/OPfiiuL) here

Comment: derp. I was trying to pipe things in thinking wrong, and overwrote the input file with blank. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

When you are running through command prompt, you have to pass the arguments as the program expecting some arguments.

try `java project1 test this`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not compiling, you are running the program.

Suggestion: Change your variable names. It is hard to distinguish "l" from "1".

Check the location of your file and see if it is different/not there.

Answer (score 0):

`String line` contains one line of text, so `line.length()` returns how many characters are there in `line`, not how many lines are there.

```
while (i < line.length()) { // reading line by line.
```

This line will test against how many characters your `line` has, not how many lines are there.  Each call to [`br.readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) will return the next line. If it returns `null`, you've reached the end of the input.

```
while (line != null) {
```

This line is testing this.

Review your code. It seems like you're iterating over `line` twice.

Comment: thank you for your comment! all I did was not compiling before running on terminal! and this code is not finished. just the guideline changed :0